# Неактивные элементы html

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование

Как сделать, чтобы при выборе любого пункта из первой группы, блокировалась вторая группа. Сейчас вторая группа блокируется сразу, потому что, при загрузке стоит первая опция.

Как это сделать на *javascript*?

*html*-код:

```
  <select name="doc" onClick="agreeForm(this.form)">
    <option value="опция1">опция1</option> 
    <option value="опция2">опция2</option> 
    <option value="опция3">опция3</option> 
  </select>


  <select name="doc1" onClick="agreeForm(this.form)">
    <option value="опция1">опция1</option> 
    <option value="опция2">опция2</option> 
    <option value="опция3">опция3</option> 
  </select>

 <script>
   function agreeForm(f) {
     if (f.doc.selected) f.doc1.disabled = 0 
      else f.doc1.disabled = 1
    }
 </script>
```

Comment: `при загрузке стоит первая опция`, а где это "при загрузке"? Убрать нельзя?

Comment: Может быть и можно, не знаю. Если делать так, то они сами и загружаются

Comment: Разъясните. Т.е. эти два элемента загружаются и `agreeForm()` первого элемента срабатывает при загрузке. Так? А что надо сделать?

Comment: Так. А надо сделать так, чтобы когда выбиралась опция из первой группы, блокировалась вторая группа, делалась неактивной

Comment: При загрузке запускается `agreeForm()` элемента и тем самым блокирует весь второй элемент. Надо, "чтобы при выборе любого пункта из первой группы, блокировалась вторая группа". Так? Но ведь она уже заблокирована... Простите, туплю... не понимаю

Comment: При загрузке страницы появляется <select> с уже выбранным 1 пунктом, этого изменить нельзя, насколько я знаю. Далее javascript определяет что в форме что-то выбрано и блокирует вторую группу. Надо сделать так, чтобы человек что-то выбрал, и только потом вторая группа заблокировалась

Comment: чуть понятнее. Вижу три варианта. 1 - если возможно - убрать запуск `agreeForm()` при загрузкею Тогда второй элемент не будет выбран. 2 - если возможно - не выбирать ничего в первом пункте, тогда `agreeForm()` не заблокирует второй элемент. 3. - не самый лучший - запустить свой JS, который разблокирует второй элемент, тогда будет Ваш вариант... Что-то типа `$(window).load(function() { [form].doc1.disabled=0; });`

Comment: Может такое пойдет http://cssdeck.com/labs/xwoifbcu